# Shell script appending filenames more than once?

Tags: sh

Sorry for the novice question. Does anyone know how to 'fix' this shell script so that it doesn't append files in sub-folders multiple times?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Function to append compression type to filename
append_compression_type() {
    local file="$1"
    local compression_type="$2"

    # Remove extension from filename
    local filename_no_ext="${file%.*}"

    # Append compression type to filename
    local new_filename="${filename_no_ext}_${compression_type}.${file##*.}"

    # Rename the file
    mv "$file" "$new_filename"

    echo "Renamed $file to $new_filename"
}

# Recursive function to process images in a directory
process_directory() {
    local directory="$1"

    # Find all image files in the directory
    find "$directory" -type f \( -iname "*.dds" \) | while read -r image_file; do
        # Get the compression type of the image
        local compression_type=$(identify -format '%C' "$image_file" 2>/dev/null)

        # If compression type is not empty
        if [ -n "$compression_type" ]; then
            append_compression_type "$image_file" "$compression_type"
        fi
    done

    # Process subdirectories
    find "$directory" -mindepth 1 -type d | while read -r subdirectory; do
        process_directory "$subdirectory"
    done
}

# Start processing from the current directory
process_directory "."
```

It works for any files in the same folder as the script but any files in sub-folder get appended multiple times as previously stated.

Comment: Your script looks pretty good from a style perspective and https://shellcheck.net only issues one inconsequential warning. Which is pretty impressive for someone asking their first S.O. question about a shell script.

Comment: @KurtisRader Full disclosure I didn't write it ChatGPT did I just changed it slightly for my purpose. I had previously been trying to achieve the same thing with powershell without the aid of ChatGPT but I was unable to get ImageMagick arguments to work while also being recursive.

Comment: **DO NOT** use code written by ChatGPT. It seldom provides correct let alone good code, in my experience. It does better with some languages, such as Python, but I would never use what it provides without extremely careful review.

Comment: @KurtisRader Fair point. I used it as a last resort after spending the better part of a week trying to write the script in powershell. Thanks for the shellcheck.net link. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line does not need the parentheses in the `find` expression:

```
find "$directory" -type f \( -iname "*.dds" \) | while read -r image_file; do
```

Did you mean to have a more complex expression inside the parens?

The reason you're getting files processed multiple times is that the `find` command above outputs not only file matching the `*.dds` glob in the `$directory` but also all subdirectories. So when you then do this you are processing the `*.dds` files in each immediate subdirectory a second time and each `*.dds` file in the second level subdirectory a third time, etcetera:

```
find "$directory" -mindepth 1 -type d | while read -r subdirectory; do
```

If you really want to process each directory independent of the others add a `-maxdepth 1` to your first `find` command. Or, just omit the second `find` block.